# How to rename a hard drive?

Tags: macos

I tried to rename the hard drive of my Macbook from "Macintosh HD" to something else without the freaking space. However, after renaming it, many of my applications showed errors immediately and I stupidly restarted my computer.

Right now, I cannot log in to my user account because of an error. Everything is blocked.

If someone can tell me how to change the harddrive name back without logging into my previous account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It seems you have another system - in that you are able to post the question. If it is a mac, you can start the problem system in [Target Disk Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_disk_mode) (if it has FireWire), connect it to the working system with a firewire cable and you should be able to change the name remotely.
2. If you can start in single-user mode [(s)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) that may allow you to bypass the problem.
3. If you start in verbose-mode, (same link as above), you may be able to see the problem.
4. If you can start from the Lion recovery disk, or a DVD, that will also allow you to change the drive name.
5. Finally, if you do get the system restarted, I urge you to check it through Disk Utility (applications > utilities).

I hope this helps.

Comment: if these ideas dont work, perhaps tell us the OS you are using, and more details of your system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
I am using a Windows right now to post the question.
I tried using su mode to rename the disc, but does not work because of some accessibility issue.
I cannot log into the system even in verbose-mode, so I can not check the Disk Utility...I replaced my DVD drive with SSD...

But the first solution should work. I just need to find another Mac and buy a firewire...It seems that I have no other solution.

Comment: what mac os are you using? This really should be solvable.

Comment: I am running Lion. Followed your first suggestion and I fixed the issue in 2 sec...Thanks so much

Comment: That's great!! Well done... I still think it a good idea to check the drive and permissions..

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should only rename your hard drive when your computer is fresh out of the box (or after you've wiped the hard drive to start fresh). The problem seems to be that there is software that will hard-code the full path to certain support files, and that includes the hard drive's name.

If you change the name before you've done anything else, this isn't a problem. As soon as you start running apps, it's a problem.

There's probably a clever way to get around this problem, but I haven't discovered it.

Comment: Totally agree...Renaming harddrive is dangerous...MacOS should have forbidden it